# How to make Jquery accordion panel focusable with down arrow key when it's open?

Tags: accessibility, accordion

We have an accessibility issue to make the accordion panel focusable with down arrow key. It is focusable only by tab key now. can we change jquery to make the panel also focusable on down arrow key?

```
 case keyCode.DOWN:             
                toFocus = this.headers[(currentIndex + 1) % length];                    
                break;
```

Comment: The down arrow key is used by many screenreaders to read the next line of text. Removing this functionality by making it do something that is not expected would be problematic to those that rely on them.

Comment: the accordion text does not receive focus with down arrow key i.e the next line after the accordion header with the default accordion jquery.